# threw an exception of type 'System.Data.StrongTypingException' C#

Tags: c#, exception

```
if ((booking.BookingsVoucher[i].RedemptionReloc != null)).
```

I am getting  exception here. RedemptionReloc has null value in dbase

```
Redemption TimeSttmp 
NULL 
Redemption Reloc 
NULL 
RedeemedCurrencyC 
NULL 
Redeemed Amo_ 
NULL
```

tried using DBNULL.value.equal(booking.BookingsVoucher[i].RedemptionReloc). But this also throw the excepetion.
Here is the exception log

> Exception in adding Voucher Details: System.Data.StrongTypingException: The value for column 'RedemptionReloc' in table 'BookingsVoucher' is DBNull. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'System.String'.

Comment: We need more information. `BookingsVoucher` is a collection of some type. What is that type and how is it defined?
What are you using to get data from the database into that type? ADO.NET with data tables? Entity Framework? A custom made solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

Change the NullValue item to Null or Empty and do you checks accordingly.

DataSet1 ds1 = new DataSet1();

```
        SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ContosoUniversity2ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        using (cn)
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Department", cn))
            {
                adapter.Fill(ds1.Department);
                foreach (DataSet1.DepartmentRow row in ds1.Department.Rows)
                {
                    if (row.Name != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(row.Name);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Which dataaccesss technology are you using Strongly typed datasets or EF?